# R is not recognizing the value of a variable

Tags: r, web-scraping

I am working with the website http://www.crowdrise.com/CDISkoll

consider the following R code that I made:

```
library("RCurl")
library("XML")
library("stringr")

user.address<-"http://www.crowdrise.com/CDISkoll"                     
user.url<-getURL(user.address)       
html <- htmlTreeParse(user.url, useInternalNodes = TRUE)

if(!is.null(xpathSApply(html,
   '//div[@class="grid1-4"]//p[@class="progressText"]',xmlValue))){
       website.goal.percentage<-
               do.call("paste",as.list(xpathSApply(html,
                '//div[@class="grid1-4"]//p[@class="progressText"]',xmlValue)))
} 

if(is.null(xpathSApply(html,
  '//div[@class="grid1-4"]//p[@class="progressText"]',xmlValue))){
          website.goal.percentage<-"Not Available"
}
```

now the website I mentioned above does not contain any information pertaining to the xpath 
`//div[@class="grid1-4"]//p[@class="progressText"]`. Thus my variable `website.goal.percentage` should be the character string `"Not Available"` . But when I perform the codes on R, it `website.goal.percentage`  returns `character(0)`....

Why is R not storing `"Not Available"` to the variable `website.goal.percentage`, and how can I fix this?

Comment: Um, check if your "if" condition is true. If it is not but you expect it to be, maybe that should be your actual question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very easy to diagnose, you should see that `xpathSApply` here returns an empty list, and how R considers that `is.null(list())` is `FALSE`. Instead you should be checking that `length(...) == 0`.

I would also recommend you use `xpathApply` because it systematically returns a list. Finally, see how your code can look a lot nicer if you use a variable:

```
nodes <- xpathApply(html, '//div[@class="grid1-4"]//p[@class="progressText"]',
                    xmlValue)

website.goal.percentage <- if(length(nodes) == 0) "Not Available" else
                           do.call("paste", nodes)
```